# MongoDB FindAndModify with concurrent requests

Tags: mongodb

I understand that this is atomic.

Does Mongo throw a *lock* exception if there are concurrent requests?

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled into this question while working on MongoDB upgrades. Unlike at the time, this question was asked, now MongoDB supports document-level locking out of the box.

From: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/

"How granular are locking in MongoDB?

Changed in version 3.0.

Beginning with version 3.0, MongoDB ships with the WiredTiger storage engine, which uses optimistic concurrency control for most read and write operations. WiredTiger uses only intent locks at the global, database, and collection levels. When the storage engine detects conflicts between two operations, one will incur a write conflict causing MongoDB to transparently retry that operation."